# Why does the BottomBarNavigationDemo example for Flutter reset the state of each view?

Tags: intellij-idea, widget, dart, flutter, bottomnavigationview

Here are my modifications to the NavigationIconViewClass

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myfluttertest/screens/bottom_navigation/profile/home_screen.dart';

class NavigationIconView {
  NavigationIconView({
    Widget icon,
    String title,
    Widget screen,
    Color color,
    TickerProvider vsync,
  }) : _icon = icon,
        _color = color,
        _title = title,
        _screen = screen,
        item = new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: icon,
          title: new Text(title),
          backgroundColor: color,
        ),
        controller = new AnimationController(
          duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
          vsync: vsync,
        ) {
            _animation = new CurvedAnimation(
              parent: controller,
              curve: const Interval(0.5, 1.0, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
            );
          }

  final Widget _icon;
  final Color _color;
  final String _title;
  final Widget _screen;
  final BottomNavigationBarItem item;
  final AnimationController controller;
  CurvedAnimation _animation;

  FadeTransition transition(BottomNavigationBarType type, BuildContext context) {
    Color iconColor;
    if (type == BottomNavigationBarType.shifting) {
      iconColor = _color;
    } else {
      final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
      iconColor = themeData.brightness == Brightness.light
          ? themeData.primaryColor
          : themeData.accentColor;
    }

    return new FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animation,
      child: new SlideTransition(
        position: new Tween<Offset>(
          begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.02), // Slightly down.
          end: Offset.zero,
        ).animate(_animation),

        child: _screen,
/*
        //TODO: PERSONALIZE VIEW IN HERE.
        ////
        child: new IconTheme(
          data: new IconThemeData(
            color: iconColor,
            size: 120.0,
          ),
          child: new Semantics(
            label: 'Placeholder for $_title tab',
            child: _icon,
          ),
        ),
       ///
*/
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here I've added a screen of type Widget to the constructor to denote the child view for each Icon view's transition. I've been testing it with the MyHomeScreen app defaulted into the project. Every time I change views from this one set to another one, the counter gets reset. Later in my application, I would like the views to get preserved so that the user will not lose their place within the tab.

Comment: Flutter has different layers. Widget layer (developers uses it usually) enforces that widgets are reconstructed on every update. So, you need to preserve state of widget, not widget itself.

Comment: @Mogol Where would the preservation best be saved?

Comment: [StatefulWidget](https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/#stateful-stateless) is good enough to start with. [Some details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkyY9WCGMi0) how widgets and states work

Comment: How would you preserve the state if you are getting data from firebase using stream builder?